# Pip default behavior conflicts with virtualenv?

Tags: python, flask, pip, virtualenv

I was following [this tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world/page/5)

When I got to `virtualenv flask` command, I received this error message:

```
Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
```

This makes sense as the point of virtualenv is to create a new environment which you can control, and the `--user` command places everything in a specific location, defeating the objective of separation of dev environment.

It seems like pip defaults to `--user` installations though, can I change this default behavior? And, even better, can I get pip to play nice with virtualenv at all times?

To clarify, here is what my terminal looks like.

```
MELCHIOR:miguelgrinberg-microblog megablanc$ virtualenv flask
New python executable in flask/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/megablanc/Dev...log/flask/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel:
  Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/megablanc/Library/Python/2.7/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/megablanc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/megablanc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1004, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Users/megablanc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 969, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/Users/megablanc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 910, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/megablanc/Dev...log/flask/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You don't need to set the `--user` flag. After you create your virtualenv (`virtualenv flask`), activate it: `source flask/bin/activate`.  Your shell should look something like `(flask) ~>`.

Once your virtualenv is activated, you should be able to pip install packages without issue.  For example, `pip install numpy`.  They'll be installed in: `lib/python2.6/site-packages/` (for whatever version of Python you are using)

Comment: I'm getting this error in the process of `virtualenv flask`, so I don't get to activate it.

Comment: Found the mistake, had set pip to default to user in ~/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf

Comment: Not on windows though. Gives you an `ACCESS DENIED` error

Answer (score 27):

what worked for me was to change the `$VIRTUAL_ENV_DIRECTORY/pyvenv.cfg` to `include-system-site-packages = true` seems hacky though.

Comment: Worked for me as well.
Source here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14327#issuecomment-757408341

Comment: You are a life saver, this worked for me as well on windows wsl virtual environment thanks alot

Answer (score 17):

There is a pip.conf file in `~/.pip.` There I changed the flag `user=true` to `user=false` using the command `gedit pip.conf`, after which I am able to create virtual environment successfully.

Comment: Link for this in the documentation: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file

Comment: in my case a manjaro update added a pip.conf file in /etc/pip.conf forcing `user=true`. Changed to false and the normal behaviour returned.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, there was a file in `/etc/pip.conf` setting the `user=true` secretly. So, every time I activated a virtualenv, that config still affected the virtualenv.

Removing that line worked for me.

Comment: This also worked for me, thanks!
On Manjaro/Arch linux this file is owned by the python-pip package and apparently this setting was introduced recently. `pacman -Qo /etc/pip.conf ` returns `/etc/pip.conf is owned by python-pip 19.2.3-1.0`.

Answer (score 7):

when your  **virutalenv myenv** is activated (source myenv/bin/activate),  remove `--user`.

Answer (score 4):

Some people suggest you to edit `/etc/pip.conf`, which (i) requires superuser privileges and (ii) may break your whole system if done wrong. So, it is better to keep it to only your user.

Open up`$HOME/.pip/pip.conf` with a text editor. If it does not exist (which is the case in my Manjaro machine), create it. Then add the lines below, save and close.

```
[global]
user=false
```

When you change a setting for your programs, prefer under `$HOME` for doing that if possible, which will (i) persist the setting among updates and reinstalling system (if you have separated your disk to `/` and `/home` partitions, of course) and (ii) will not possibly break further upgrades of the program, in this case, `pip`.

Answer (score 4):

Check if your the `PIP_USER` environment variable is set.
That fixed the issue for me.
If you are using [GitPod then this is a known issue](https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/1997#issuecomment-708480259).

Comment: This actually is the best answer if you only seek a temporary workaround and don't want to change any global settings.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, I only changed the `$VIRTUAL_ENV_DIRECTORY/pyvenv.cfg` to

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

The default setting

```
include-system-site-packages = false
```

Note:

```
> python --version 
Python 3.8.3 r c 1
```

Comment: Worked for me. Explanation please?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was doing a `make test` for the python `disco` mapreduce library.

So I modified the `Makefile` test section and removed the `--user` flag.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a custom python installation from anaconda was interfering with the system installation. Check `which pip`... the solution is to either remove or move the custom installation of python.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question was asked quite a pretty while ago, maybe another answer would be useful to someone anyway.

If the described issue happens only when trying to install packages to virtualenv which is **outside your home** directory, the problem might be that user account you logged in does not have permissions on the folder you are trying to install to.

Use **chown** to change / raise user's permission on the folder where target virtual environment is placed, for example:

`chown username /var/www/your-webproject-folder/ -r`

or

`sudo chown username /var/www/your-webproject-folder/ -r`

if you have to do it with root.