# PyCharm: Can't install opencv-contrib-python

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, sift

I can't install opencv-contrib-python on PyCharm using the Setting options provided by PyCharm. I get these error everytime I tried first not using the --user option, such as in image 1:[image: image 1]

Then I tried using the --user option, and I got what is showed in image 2[image: image 2]

My knowledge of Python is very weak and I don't need to get it better right now. I have a script I need to run for a very close presentation (in the script there are many section with many examples of how to use SIFT, image homography, and other stuff used in image processing and artificial vision. I can't run the SIFT part, this is why I need opencv-contrib-python). I'm using opencv 3.4.3.18 and I need to make the script working for that distribution!

I haven't found anything of useful since now and I'm in quite a hurry and still without a solution.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using the pip from the command line?

Comment: This whole question is really (or should be) about pip.  It has almost nothing to do with Python (unless you are going to post some code).  I suspect that the issue is because it is being installed in a venv.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip default behavior conflicts with virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604952/pip-default-behavior-conflicts-with-virtualenv)