# ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Actually, I wanted to create my first django project. After I did some coding in the cmd then I opened the code using visual studio code. I selected the python interpreter on the status bar, then I changed it to the python interpreter installed in my digital environment. After that, I got message that linter pylint is not installed. After I installed that, these errors occurred.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460163/ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-the-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-syste)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604952/pip-default-behavior-conflicts-with-virtualenv)

Answer (score 21):

[This solution](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14327#issuecomment-757408341) worked for me. Just repeating it here:

```
1. Go to the `pyvenv.cfg` file in the Virtual environment folder
2. Set the `include-system-site-packages` to `true` and save the change
3. Reactivate the virtual environment.
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm running Windows 11 > Git Bash (Windows Terminal
Version: 1.16.10262.0).

Answer (score 0):

I did encounter the same error when I wanted to install a python module.This is because you want to install a user specific module in your project and the virtual environment user-site packages are not visible.The --user installs a python package for the current user rather than the users of the system.You can use this

```
pip install <python package>
```

instead of `pip install --user <python package>`

Answer (score -3):

As described [in this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14327), you have to set "global module installation" to be true.

You can do that from File > Preferences > Settings:

[image]

Comment: This is a terrible workaround. The whole point of these tools is to avoid installing globally