# How to create a venv based on an existing interpreter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, interpreter, python-venv

In the system I work on (Ubuntu), the admin has installed all necessary packages (torch,tensorflow,cuda, matplotlib, etc) in this path:

```
/usr/bin/python3.10
```

[image]
[image]

If I check "inherit global site-packages" I can access all necessary packages.
I want to know how to create a virtual env based on this interpreter to run Jupiter Notebook?

I don't want to use Pycharm's Jupyter capability.
I want to use Jupyter notebook independently and use this venv.

To create a new virtual env I've done these steps:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.10 MY-env
source ./MY-env/bin/activate
```

And then to add my venv to jupyter kernels:

```
pip install ipykernel 
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=MY-env
```

In the Terminal when I run jupyter-lab, I select My-env from the "Change Kernel" option.
for testing I imported torch, but I got the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

While torch is installed and exists in the site-packages. It means it hasn't detected site-packages of `/usr/bin/python3.10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72779191/8385336) worked for me:

1. Go to the `pyvenv.cfg` file in the Virtual environment folder
2. Set the `include-system-site-packages` to `true` and save the change
3. Reactivate the virtual environment.