# Docker Airflow - ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, airflow

## GOAL

- Since 2022 Sept 19 The release of Apache Airflow 2.4.0
- Airflow supports ExternalPythonOperator
- I have asked the main contributors as well and I should be able to add 2 python virtual environments to the base image of Airflow Docker 2.4.1 and be able to rune single tasks inside a DAG.
- My goal is to use multiple host python virtualenvs that built from a local requirements.txt.
- using ExternalPythonOperator to run them (Each of my dags just execute a timed python function)

## CODE

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.4.1-python3.8
RUN python3 -m venv /opt/airflow/venv1
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN . /opt/airflow/venv1/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

#### TERMINAL INPUT

`docker build -t my-image-apache/airflow:2.4.1 .`

#### TERMINAL OUTPUT

```
[+] Building 4.3s (9/9) FINISHED                                                                                                                
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.55kB                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/apache/airflow:2.4.1-python3.8                                                                  1.2s
 => [auth] apache/airflow:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/apache/airflow:2.4.1-python3.8@sha256:5f9f4eff86993e11893f371f591aed73cf2310a96d84ae8fddec11857c6345da     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 37B                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [2/4] RUN python3 -m venv /opt/airflow/venv1                                                                                           2.2s
 => [3/4] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                          0.0s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN . /opt/airflow/venv1/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt                                                   0.8s
------                                                                                                                                          
 > [4/4] RUN . /opt/airflow/venv1/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt:
#9 0.621 ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
#9 0.763 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
#9 0.763 You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/airflow/venv1/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -o errexit -o nounset -o nolog -c . /opt/airflow/venv1/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

## Tried Solutions

- I dont use --user flag, and in my case this is a Dockerfile commands - [Pip default behavior conflicts with virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604952/pip-default-behavior-conflicts-with-virtualenv)
- https://splunktool.com/error-can-not-perform-a-user-install-user-sitepackages-are-not-visible-in-this-virtualenv

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.4.1-python3.8

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/airflow/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Install dependencies:
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Same error as above

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.4.1-python3.8
ADD . /opt/airflow/
WORKDIR /opt/airflow/

RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Same error as above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dockerfile [CORRECT]

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.4.1-python3.8

# Compulsory to switch parameter
ENV PIP_USER=false

#python venv setup
RUN python3 -m venv /opt/airflow/venv1

# Install dependencies:
COPY requirements.txt .

# --user   <--- WRONG, this is what ENV PIP_USER=false turns off
#RUN /opt/airflow/venv1/bin/pip install --user -r requirements.txt  <---this is all wrong
RUN /opt/airflow/venv1/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PIP_USER=true
```

Comment: Ty very much for sharing the solution. After 2 days of banging my head, finally figure out the working solution, courtesy you !!